# Layer audio files with ffmpeg?

Tags: javascript, ffmpeg, fluent-ffmpeg

The following code adds `part2.m4a` after `part1.m4a` is finished. How do I combine them so they start playing at the same time?

```
ffmpeg('part1.m4a')
  .input('part2.m4a')
  .mergeToFile('part3.m4a')
```

Comment: u may be able to use the 'map' switch to overlay 2 audio tracks

Comment: `map` cannot be used for overlay. Filtering is required. I don't know the syntax of fluent-ffmpeg. Can you use a direct ffmpeg command?